# Setting RGBA channels of Color using a Converter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, ivalueconverter

I've got four sliders that set the values of RGBA channels of a `Color` using a converter as shown below:

```
 <Slider Width="200" x:Name="redSlider" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="1.0" 
         Value="{Binding NewColor, Converter={StaticResource colorChannelConverter}, ConverterParameter ='R'}"/>
```

The converter code:

```
 public class ColorChannelConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var c = (Color)value;
        var p = (string)parameter;
        double channel = 0.0;
        switch(p)
        {
            case "R":
                channel = c.R;
                break;
            case "G":
                channel = c.G;
                break;
            case "B":
                channel = c.B;
                break;
            case "A":
                channel = c.A;
                break;

        }
        return channel / 255.0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // I'd like to do something like:
        // var d = (byte)((double)value*255);
        // if((string)parameter == "R") NewColor.R = d;
        // item for other channels
        // return NewColor;
        // Note that I don't want to touch NewColor's other channels!
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now acquiring a channel is simple as you can see. However, the converter doesn't have access to `NewColor` property so that it can set its individual channels. How can I go about doing this **without using another control that would collect the values of the four sliders**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding to the entire color, you really only want to bind to a single component of the color, such as `MyColor.R` for example. The problem is that the built in `Color` struct is not observable, so the view will not update appropriately.

The way I solved this same issue in a color picker application I am working on was by creating a custom class to represent my color (which I called `ObservableColor`) that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has observable properties for the individual color channels. Internally, it uses a `System.Windows.Media.Color` as storage and exposes it as a property for other parts of the application that need to display the color.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
class ObservableColor : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Color mColor;

    public Color Color
    {
        get { return mColor; }
        set
        {
            // Update mColor and fire property change notifications for "Color"
            // and for all of the individual channel properties
        }
    }

    public byte A
    {
        get { return mColor.A; }
        set
        {
            // Update mColor.A and fire property change notifications for "Color" and "A"
        }
    }

    public byte R
    {
        // Same as A, but for the R color channel
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Using something like this would allow you to bind to `NewColor.R` instead of `NewColor`. This way your converter only needs to return the value for that channel instead of returning the whole color (which it has no way of knowing, as you found).

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed what I'm going to do now. Making individual properties for RGBA and HSV.